# laravel registration : add error to validation generated outside of validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.4

so this is my register controller

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{

    return Validator;
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
   register here 
}
```

I want to add a referral system to this process basically when registering user might send a refer_id (id of a user who has referred this user to website), I'll check that refer id and if it was valid I'll do some my thing

I want to change my validation function to something like

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{

    $validation = Validator::make($data, [
        'email' => ['required' ,'email' , 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->where('rep_id' ,  $this->rep->id) ] ,
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'refer_id' => 'present|numeric',

    ]);

    if(isset($data['refer_id']))
    {
        $refer = User::find($data['refer_id']) ;
        if($refer)
        {
            // return error : refer id is wrong !
        }
    }

    return $validation ;
}
```

my problem is this part

```
// return error: refer id is wrong!
```

how can I return registering the user with this error back to view or add this error to validation errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has a clean approach to do this

try this

```
'refer_id' => 'nullable|exists:users,id'
```

or may be

```
'refer_id' => 'present|numeric|exists:users,id'
```